# Redis Facade cannot get session data

Tags: laravel

I set the session driver to redis, but I don't get session data from Redis Facade.

This is config/session.php

```php
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),
```

This is .env

```php
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_CONNECTION="session-connection"
```

This is config/database.php

```php
'redis' => [

        'session-connection' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
            'prefix' => 'session:',
        ],

    ],
```

These are codes which run in the php artisan tinker:

```php
>>> session(['key'=>'value']);
=> null

>>> session('key');
=> "value"

>>> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
>>> Redis::connection('session-connection')->get('key')
=> null

>>> Redis::connection('session-connection')->keys('*')
=> []
```

---

But Redis Facade can get Cache data, and I don't know why session cannot.

These are settings related to the cache.

This is config/cache.php

```php
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
'stores' => [
        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'cache-connection',
            'lock_connection' => 'cache-lock',
        ],
],
//'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_cache_'),
```

This is .env

```php
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

This is config/database.php

```php
'redis' => [

        'cache-connection' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
            'prefix' => 'cache:',
        ],

        'cache-lock' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => '1',
            'prefix' => 'cache-lock:',
        ],

    ],
```

These are codes which run in the php artisan tinker:

```php
>>> Cache::set('cachekey',1);
=> true

>>> Cache::get('cachekey');
=> "1"

>>> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
>>> Redis::connection('cache-connection')->get('cachekey')
=> "1"

>>> Redis::connection('cache-connection')->keys('*')
=> [
     "cache:cachekey",
   ]
```

Any ideas? Thank you!